# Polymer:Route sections don't display

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm using pageJS along iron-pages to display different pages. Routes are working, because console logs are fine.

But I'm using this code to display the content:

```
<a data-route="test" href="#!test">test</a>
<iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
<section data-route="test">TEST</section>
</iron-pages>
```

*Note*: If selected="test" it is displayed.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: That the text, more exactly the section doesn't display.

Comment: the section attribute is supposed to be `data-route`

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake when posting here. It doesn't work even I'f it's *data-route*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using polymer starter kit, you need to put your route in the routing.html file. What this file does is just tells pagejs to set the route variable to "test" when going to the url "#!test". So if you just wanted to have an on-click handler that sets the route variable to test when you click the `<a>` tag, that would work too.

Comment: As far as I did that before doing the post, still I'll leave it here

Comment: <script src="page/page.js"></script>

<script>
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
  page('/', function() {
    console.log("url=>home");
    app.route = "home";
  });
  page('test', function() {
    console.log("url=>test");
    app.route = "test";
  });
  page({
    hashbang:true
  });

});
</script>